Getting specific index within nested list
Trying to find a way to access an index within a nested list in R.  the location I'm looking at looks like this:
data[["group"]][["categories"]][[3]][["subcategories"]][[3]][["stats"]]

However, the [[3]]s are random; when I update the data they can be any numbers 1-20, so sometimes the location will be, for example:
data[["group"]][["categories"]][[6]][["subcategories"]][[5]][["stats"]]

The index I want is always called [["stats"]], and the other character-named indices are always the same, but the number-named indices are random.  There's only one [["stats"]] index within the list, but it moves location in the numbered indices each time the data is updated. Is there a simple way to access this [["stats"]] index regardless of what numbers precede it in the list?
